# search for non-closed, non-duplicate questions?

Tags: support, search, user-interface

I usually try to find questions where I can help. That would be an "answers:0" search (perhaps also with "votes:0" to avoid doomed questions), but that still brings many closed / duplicate questions. And I still need to click the "newest" tab. Is there an easier way to find what I want?

Comment: Add `closed:no` to your search

Comment: Thanks @Bart. Will that avoid duplicates as well?

Comment: If they were closed as such, yes.

Comment: Cool. Might want to answer so I can accept. Do you also know if there's a URL fragment I can add to sort by date? I'd love to have bookmarks with something like "[topic] answers:0 closed:no sort-by-date"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=topic%20closed%3a0%20answers%3a0

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I guess I should have right-clicked on the tab to see the URL for newest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To filter out the closed questions (which includes those closed as duplicate), just add `closed:no` to your search.

Comment: Useful, although merged style duplicates with answers still come up, eg a search for java closed:0 answers:0 still brings up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449406/arraylist-in-java I've tried a few varients of the search string but not found anything so far